# Return value of system() is not return value of executed program

Tags: c, return, program-entry-point

I would like to execute an executable file whose main() returns 2 using `system()`. 
This is what I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *agrv[])
{
    char command[7];
    strcpy(command, "./test1");
    printf("The return value: %d\n", system(command));

    return 0;
}
```

and `test1` is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("test1 has been executed and its return value is 2\n");

    return 2;
}
```

This is what I'm getting

```
test1 has been executed and its return value is 2
The return value: 512
```

My question is why I'm getting `512`.

Comment: @AntonH OP is not intending to print a string, though.

Comment: @AntonH nope you are incorrect

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You're right, I read too quickly.

Comment: `command` is too small. This is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: ***[Here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_22598356.html)*** is a link where user gets 512.  In this case it is in conjunction with SQL calls.

Comment: Sigh. `strcpy` should be avoided. See: [strcpy(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) and [MSDN strcpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The return value of system is actually the return value of waitpid() under POSIX.

`status` actually has a lot of information embedded in it:

From the system(3) manpage:

> The following macros may be used to test the manner of exit of the
>   process.  One of the first three macros will evaluate to a non-zero
>   (true) value:
>
> #### `WIFEXITED(status)`
>
> `True` if the process terminated normally by a call to _exit(2) or exit(3).
>
> #### `WIFSIGNALED(status)`
>
> `True` if the process terminated due to receipt of a signal.
>
> #### `WIFSTOPPED(status)`
>
> `True` if the process has not terminated, but has stopped and can be restarted.
>   This macro can be true only if the wait call specified the
>   `WUNTRACED` option or if the child process is being traced (see ptrace(2)).
>
> Depending on the values of those macros, the following macros produce
>   the remaining status information about the child process:
>
> #### `WEXITSTATUS(status)`
>
> If `WIFEXITED(status)` is `true`, evaluates to the low-order 8 bits of the argument passed to _exit(2) or exit(3) by the child.
>
> #### `WTERMSIG(status)`
>
> If `WIFSIGNALED(status)` is `true`, evaluates to the number of the signal that caused the 
>   termination of the process.
>
> #### `WCOREDUMP(status)`
>
> If `WIFSIGNALED(status)` is `true`, evaluates as true if the termination of the process was accompanied by the creation of a core file containing an image of the process when the signal was received.
>
> #### `WSTOPSIG(status)`
>
> If `WIFSTOPPED(status)` is `true`, evaluates to the number of the signal that caused the process to stop.

### Solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    char command[PATH_MAX]; /* PATH_MAX is defined in sys/syslimits.h, included by limits.h */
    strcpy(command, "./test1");
    status = system(command);
    if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
          printf("The return value: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
          printf("The program exited because of signal (signal no:%d)\n", WTERMSIG(status));
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where are `WIFEXITED ... etc` functions? I'm getting errors.

Comment: The `WIFEXITED`, etc. _macros_ should be documented with either `system(3)` or `wait(2)` functions. Otherwise see POSIX.1 (2013)  [sys/wait.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_wait.h.html)

Comment: #include <cstdlib> on C++

Comment: @kingsjester true ;) but this isn't a C++ question.

Answer (score 6):

Quote `man 3 system`:

> The value returned is `-1` on error (e.g. `fork`(2) failed), and the return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is in the format specified in `wait`(2). Thus, the exit code of the command will be `WEXITSTATUS(status)`.

`man 2 wait` shows the other information packed into the `status` returned by `system`(3).

- `512` means the program exited with exit status 2.
- `2` would mean the program was killed by signal 2 (SIGINT).

---

Note that that the string `./test1` takes 8 characters because of the trailing NUL. Your `strcpy` is clobbering some memory outside of `command`. Fix:

```
char command[8];
strcpy(command, "./test1");
```

Of course, there's no reason to make a copy in the first place.

```
const char* command = "./test1";
system(command)
```

or even

```
system("./test1")
```

Comment: now how am I supposed to get `2`? I need to use this value. Everyone is addressing the problem but not the solution.

Comment: @CroCo if you don't understand the problem(s), then you won't *understand* the answer. The goal is for you to _learn_ to fix mistakes yourself, not free debugging.

Comment: @mctylr, if you did your best to fix the problems but you failed then there is no problem to let another people debug the code. and please stop showing off like you are the only guy who is working hard.

Comment: @CroCo, I told you the soltuon. "The exit code of the command will be `WEXITSTATUS(status)`."

Comment: @CroCo, ikegami has answered your question on why and how to interpret the **return value** from `system` such you can determine the **exit code** of the command `system` executed. Additionally they noted that you have a second problem that is interfering with your desired outcome. If you don't understand this answer, then clarify _what part do you not understand?_

Answer (score 0):

This is, in fact, undefined behavior. `command` only holds 7 characters, but your string `"./test1"` has 8, including the null-terminator. You'll need to either increase the size of `command`, or just call `system` directly with the literal string: `system("./test1")`

Comment: +1 This doesn't totally answer the OP's question, but definitely addresses a serious bug.

Comment: Well, technically, since OP is invoking UB, the return value of 512 *could* be a result of UB.

Comment: Would have been better as a comment.

Comment: This is not the answer to the OP's question

Comment: Actually the OP's question is in fact _why_: _"My question is why I'm [sic] getting 512[?]"_