# C++: How to pass arguments to an executable?

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls

I have 2 programs (executables) Client and Server. Client captures 2 integers from the user, and transmit them to Server. Server does the calculation and returns to Client.

But I don't know how to pass argument from Client to Server.

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){

        argv[0] = "server"; // the Server program, located in the same directory

        int int1, int2;
        char operator1;

        //data entry
        cout << "Please enter 2 integers" << endl;
        cin >> int1 >> int2;
        cout << "Please enter a character, either a + or a -" << endl;
        cin >> operator1;

        int PID = fork(); // creating a child process

        while (operator1 == '+' || operator1 =='-') { 
            if (PID == 0){
                execl(arg[0], "server", NULL); // child process (server code).
//How to pass the items to this program?
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else if (PID < 0){
                perror("execution failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        // re-enter data
        cout << "Please enter 2 integers" << endl;
        cin >> int1 >> int2;
        cout << "Please enter a character, either a + or a -" << endl;
        cin >> operator1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This might be helpful for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810889/return-value-of-system-is-not-return-value-of-executed-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are passed as additional `char *` parameters to `execl`().

Convert your parameters to `char` strings, and just pass them as additional parameters to `execl`().

Or use several other, alternative, versions of `exec`(), like `execvp`(), if the alternative parameter passing conventions they use would be more convenient for you.

Comment: is is like this: `const char int1, int2, operator1;` and then `execl(argv[0], int1, int2, operator1, NULL);` ?

Comment: No. execl() takes char * arguments, pointing to null-terminated strings.